# ASK: How to get recurring test account on PayPal Payment Pro /PayFlow?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have signup test account for PayPal Payment Pro/PayFlow (at this url https://manager.paypal.com). and now I want to test **Recurring Billing Service** on PayFlow, but it need to pay $99 for setup fee and another fee regarding monthly fee and transaction fee.

I just want to get this **Recurring Billing Service** for testing mode, without pay it first. how can i get this? or maybe enable this recurring feature without paying it?

[how to get this service for testing only without pay it first?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDlrt.png)

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test the recurring billing there is no need to purchase it . Once you login to your manager account just click on the advertisement to sign up for the recurring billing and click on continue and that's it . Recurring should be added in the test mode .

You can check whether the recurring billing is added or not by clicking on the "Home" and then it should something like below :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Eshan, It's working!! I always stuck on payment page. I think It's need to be paid before we continue. once again thank you Eshan

Comment: You welocme!! . Yeah the card info is required if you decided to go live .